# WebView in Activity Scaling

Tags: android, webview, scale, html-email

I've an Widget that opens HTML-Emails in a WebView on a Activity. My problem is that i'm using..

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

and the Content is sometimes too small. Its not possible to Scale the content of the Webview. 
Can anyone explain me how to make a Scale-Function like any other webbrowser.

Comment: Have you tried "webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);"

Answer (score 1):

try **setSupportZoom(true)** setting method